# Remove rows of 3D array which are present in a 4D array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D numpy array=a containing coordinates of points in space.
By transforming this array through matrix operations, I got 4D numpy array, such that for each row of a there is a corresponding 3D block within 4D array after matrix transformations(including identity operation). So the zero axis of both arrays is equal.

Now, I need to find if the any row having index [i] is present or not in the jth row if present then either remove i or j.(doesn't matter if its i or j). Also i =! j since we have an identity operation. As an example to clarify:

```
>>> a  # 3d array
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[0, 2, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])

>>> b  #4d array after applying transformation to 3d array(a)
array([[[[0, 1, 2],
         [0, 0, 2]],

        [[0, 0, 0],
         [2, 1, 1]],

        [[0, 2, 1],
         [0, 0, 1]]],


       [[[2, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 2]],

        [[0, 2, 2],
         [2, 0, 0]],

        [[2, 2, 2],
         [1, 0, 2]]],


       [[[0, 2, 1],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[2, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 2]],

        [[2, 0, 1],
         [2, 2, 0]]]])
```

Now, if you look closely, the a is same as b[:,0]. The reason is identity transformation.So we certainly do not want to compare a[0] with b[0].
The a[1] = b[2,0] , So the code should remove either a[1] or a[2] but not both.
The final result should be:

```
>>> output
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2]]])
```

OR,

```
>>> output
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[0, 2, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

**First sol.**
The sol. so far I have is this,

```
def giveuniquestructures_fast(marray, symarray, noofF):
    """ Removes configurations ith (2d block of marray) which are found in symmarray at jth position such that i != j """

# noofF is the number of points in each configuration(i.e. noofF = len(marray[0])
# The shape of the two arrays is, marray 3D-array(positions, nofF, 3),
# symarray 4D-array(positions, symmetryopration, noofF, 3)


print("Sorting the input arrays:\\n")

symarray = sort4D(symarray)    # sorting the symarray(4D-array)

marray = sorter3d_v1(marray)    # sorting the marray(3D-array)
print("sorting is complete now comparison is starting: ")

delindex = np.empty(0, dtype=int) 
delcheck = False
print("The total number of configurations are", len(marray))

 # flattening the array to reduce one dimension

symarray = symarray.reshape(marray.shape[0],-1,3*noofF) 
marray = marray.reshape(-1, 3*noofF)
bol = np.ones(symarray.shape[0], dtype=bool)
     # boolean array for masking the symarray along 0-axis

for i in range(len(marray)):

        print("checking %dth configuration for symmetrical equivalencey \\n" % i)
        bol[i] = False
        bol1 = marray[i] == symarray[bol]
        bol1 = bol1.all(-1)
        bol[i] = True # setting it back to true for next run

        if bol1.any() :

            delindex = np.append(delindex, i)
            delcheck = True

if delcheck:

    marray = np.delete(marray, delindex, 0)

print("Search for UNique configurations are ending now :\\n")
return marray.reshape(-1, noofF,3)  # converting back to input shape
```

-----------just in case if u want to see the sorting functions ------------

```
def sorter3d_v1(a):

    """sorts the 1D blocks within 2D blocks of array in order of first column, 2nd column, 3rd column"""

    print("Input array is \\n", a)
    print("shape of input array is ",a.shape)
    ind = np.lexsort((a[:,:,2], a[:,:,1], a[:,:,0]), axis=1)  # getting the sorter index

    s = np.arange(len(a))[:,np.newaxis] # getting the evenly distributed number array  based on length of ind to select the sorted

    a = a[s,ind,:]

    print("sorted array is \\n")
    print(a)

    return  a
```

As you may have guessed the problem with this function is efficiency. If the input array has rows in even 1/10th of million, it takes a lot of time for the loop to run. The bottleneck actual lies at the statement which is using np.all() function, i.e.

```
bol1 = bol1.all(-1)
```

Any help on improving it will be highly appreciated. I hope it is not confusing.

**Second solution**
The second solution which I was able to code with vectorization:

```
def giveuniquestructures_fast_v1(marray, symarray, noofF):
    """The new implementation of the previous function (uniquestructures_fast) """

    # The shape of the two arrays is, marray 3D-array(positions, nofF, 3),
    # symarray 4D-array(positions, symmetryopration, noofF, 3)

    try:

        if (len(marray) != len(symarray)):
            raise Exception("The length of the two arrays doesn't match")

    except Exception:
        raise

    print("Sorting the input arrays:\\n")

    symarray = sort4D(symarray)  # sorting the barray(4D-array)

    marray = sorter3d_v1(marray)  # sorting the marray(3D-array)
    print("sorting is complete now comparison is starting: ")
    print("The total number of configurations is", len(marray))

    # flattening the array to reduce one dimension

    symarray = symarray.reshape(symarray.shape[0], -1, 3 * noofF)
    marray = marray.reshape(-1, 3 * noofF)

    # Batch operation may give Memory error in case array is big!!! 

    bol = marray[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:] == symarray  # 4d array
    maskindices = np.arange(len(bol)) # to falsify the identity matrix operaterated values
    bol[maskindices[:,np.newaxis], maskindices[:,np.newaxis]] = False  # setting the identity rows value to False
    delindices   = np.where(bol.all(-1)) # The first and second tuple entries are relevant for next step

    # Need to check for swapping indices as possibility of removing both equal arrays may happen

    # removing the configurations which are symmetrically equivalent
    marray = np.delete(marray, np.unique(delindices,axis=-1)[0], 0)

    # reverting the dimensions back to the input array dimensions

    marray = marray.reshape(-1, noofF, 3)
    print("Search for UNique configurations are ending now :\\n")
    return marray
```

**Problem with second sol.**
The vectorization does not help when the array gets big enough to raise memory error. Any ideas?!!

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten about your question that we discussed almost a month ago. Unfortunately I haven't had the time to look at it again, so I've just deleted my answer which didn't address your question. For future visitors: some discussion can be found [here in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182212/room-for-andras-deak-and-malik).